[Monitoring and Alerts Configuration for Google reCAPTCHA v3 Enterprise Edition]
I am reaching out for technical assistance regarding our implementation of Google reCAPTCHA v3 Enterprise Edition. We have successfully created keys for our sites and are now looking to set up monitoring for daily API usage.
We aim to track and monitor the daily request volumes to the reCAPTCHA service and set up alerts based on certain usage thresholds. Could you provide detailed information on how we can configure these aspects within our management console? Additionally, we would be interested in knowing if there is a specific dashboard or tool that allows us to manage these settings efficiently.
I would appreciate any documentation or step-by-step guide you could provide to facilitate this process.
Thank you for your time and I look forward to your prompt response.
We have successfully created keys for our sites and are now looking to set up monitoring for daily API usage.

Hi.
In the reCaptcha section of GCP you have a built-in dashboard. And from there you could also see metrics in Metrics Explorer. And from there you can use that info to create alerts.
Cheers

can you help me with more details, I have a guide to create, but it seems is not working, can you help me in a step by step to get the right configuration?

In the doc below you have all the documentation in a step by step on how to implement recaptcha depending on your use case
https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/setup-overview-web
if you have a particular error, post it please.

You can set up an alert at https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerting following these instructions. For the reCAPTCHA API you would add the following:

Metric: Consumed API > API > Request Count
Filters:

Service: recaptchaenterprise.googleapis.com
Method: google.cloud.recaptchaenterprise.v1.RecaptchaEnterpriseService.CreateAssessment




Then you can "Configure alert trigger", for example alert when "Above threshold" when your QPS to this service goes above some acceptable threshold. Or instead of "rate" you could change the window function to monitor "count" and alert when your request count goes above some threshold.
Aside from Alerting you can view API usage using the "Metrics explorer" dashboard in the same way https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/metrics-explorer which the same query as above (Metric + Filters)
